# Chrome packaged app oauth redirect problems due to different extension id

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-chrome-app

I am using an oauth provider with a chrome extension and they are only able to provide me with one client id at this time. Their redirect uri must be the same between my chrome app, android app, and ios app.  However the instructions on the chrome app documentation say that my redirect url should be something like "https://' + extension_id + '.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb.

My chrome extension, android app, and ios app all have different extension ids.

Is there any way to force my chrome extension and package android and ios apps to use the same extension id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `key` defined in your `manifest.json` file, then it will be used to generate your extension id.

Reference: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/key.html

There isn't currently a way to force a specific ID without that key, and there's definitely no way to get the key from an ID: it's derived from the SHA-256 hash of the key.

However, if you can get your key from your CRX file, then you can put it in your manifest and `cca` will use that to generate the extension id for your Android and iOS packaged apps.

Comment: Thank you! That worked- now my chrome extension, ios app, and android app are all using the same extension id and I only need one client id from my oauth2 provider.  That was exactly what I needed.